# Seamless Video Loop HTML 5 Video.js

Tags: html, video, video.js

Really can't figure out how to get my video looping seamlessly.

At the moment there is slight pause when it starts the loop, i'm using video.js and this is all new to me.

This is my code in DW,

```
<video width="640" height="264" id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" poster="1.png" preload="none" p controls loop  >
      <source src="1.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Preload the video with the 'preload' option.
Loop the video with the 'loop' option.

Details here: https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/options.md

Comment: Thanks, i've tried that but there is still a noticeable delay, this is for an app so i'm hoping it will work different then what i'm seeing in the browser, if not guess i'll have to mess with the .js source code.

Comment: any joy with this i have the exact same problem

Comment: Have you tried using a second video element, loading the video into that, and having it buffered and teed up. When playback on the first video element ends, hide it, and show the second, and then play the second. Repeat...

Comment: no i'm not sure how i'd go about doing that, ive got working now and looping ok the only problem is when it reloads the skin appears for a second when full screen on ipad, any ideas? this is so frustraing! hers my code, vid=sym.$("rec_1");vid.html('<video width= "238" height= "151" src= "video/1.mp4"  type= "video/mp4" loop= "loop" controls= "controls" preload= "auto"</video>');

Comment: So it loops without rebuffering now? That's good! As for the reload -- not sure what you can do there. Have you tried setting the 'poster' image? Maybe if that appears instead of the skin it might look better?